# How can I use /viscurl/ in gdal python to load an Open Data url into posgres?

Tags: python, c++, postgresql, gdal, ogr

I am trying to load an Open Data dataset into a postgres database using GDAL Python binding. I have successfully written code to load in remote files from places like github and ftp servers but gdal consistently gives me errors when trying to load data from Socrata.

I have been able to obtain the dataset's info with the following command:

```
ogrinfo -ro -al -so 'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/mwzb-yiwb/rows.csv'  --config CPL_CURL_VERBOSE YES --config CPL_VSIL_CURL_USE_HEAD NO --config OGR_SKIP GeoJSONSeq
```

I set `CPL_VSIL_CURL_USE_HEAD NO` because request fail when gdal tries to request just the HEAD of the link.

I am now trying to load the dataset into postgres using the python binding.

```py
url = "/vsicurl/" + "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/mwzb-yiwb/rows.csv"
gdal.SetConfigOption('CPL_VSIL_CURL_USE_HEAD', 'NO')
srcDS = gdal.OpenEx(url)
```

...but I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR 4: /vsicurl/https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/mwzb-yiwb/rows.csv' not recognized as a supported file format.
```